# Modify column in list of lists

Tags: elixir

I have a list of list, as such

```
list = [[title, description, ~N[2018-01-01 23:00:07], comment, user],
       [title, description, ~N[2018-03-02 12:10:18], comment, user]]
```

Now I need to convert every NaiveDateTime to Erlang date (or Unix timestamp).

I believe I can do something like

```
new_list = Enum.map(list,&modify_date/1)

def modify_date(list) do
  ##
end
```

But I can't figure out how to make `modify_date/1` only affect the third element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and most idiomatic way in Elixir of solving this problem is by directly pattern matching. This will increase readability considerably as contrasted to the other solutions presented so far.

You are correct about utilizing `Enum.map(list, &modify_date/1)`, and if you pattern match like this:

`modify_date([title, description, date, comment, user])`

you can easily pick out any data that you require and manipulate accordingly.

A full working solution is presented below, which you can run as `A.run()`:

```
 defmodule A do
  def run do
    [["title", "description", ~N[2018-01-01 23:00:07], "comment", "user"], ["title", "description", ~N[2018-03-02 12:10:18], "comment", "user"]]
    |> process
  end

  def process(list) do
    Enum.map(list, &modify_date/1)
  end

  def modify_date([title, description, date, comment, user]) do
    unix_timestamp = date
      |> DateTime.from_naive!("Etc/UTC")
      |> DateTime.to_unix()

    [title, description, unix_timestamp, comment, user]    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new_list = update_in(list, [Access.all(), Access.at(2)], &modify_date/1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer list to tuple also.

```
list = [["fds", "fds", ~N[2018-01-01 23:00:07], "sfd", "fdsa"],
       ["fds", "fds", ~N[2018-03-02 12:10:18], "fds", "fdsa"]]
Enum.map(list, fn x ->
  IO.inspect x|> List.to_tuple |> elem(2)
end)
```